# Make links disable in menu

Tags: jquery

```
<li ><a href="" id="close">Close</a></li>
<script>
$(document).ready(fucnction(){
$(#close).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
});
</script>
```

After writing this i am not able to see the menu list to disable a menu item by using jquery?

Comment: wrap `#close` in quotes .

Comment: even then i am unable to see the menu

Comment: "function" word spelling also wrong in document ready

Comment: yeah yeah i modified it.But now i am not getting the link close disabled? what might be the reason?

Comment: I am getting the link disabled towards the right not in the original position.Why?

Answer (score 4):

> Two Mistakes in your code:
>             1) you missed quotes for selectors
>              2) "function" word spelling also wrong in document ready

```
 $("#close").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

Comment: even then i am unable to see the menu?

Comment: this was the problem in your code. you ask a question right.

Comment: I am not getting the link disabled.What might be the reason?

Comment: I am getting the link disabled towards the right not in the original position.Why?

Comment: verify your css .ui-state-disabled

Comment: in .css file what should we write the attributes

Comment: you can disable only button elements. if tag means like(div,span) off the click event and set any color for disabled using css

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js "></script>

</head>

<body >

<li ><a href="" id="close">Close</a></li>


</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#close').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting the link towards the right in the menu list

Comment: please share your css